# newspaper - plural vs singular

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I stumbled upon such a sentence in a book:

> Every year millions of acres of forest are cleared to make the paper for **newspaper**.

In my opinion, the plural form, **newspapers**, would sound more natural.

What would be the difference in meaning between the singular and plural forms in such a sentence?

Comment: It is an odd usage. We use _newspaper_ as a non-count noun for sheets of old newspapers used as wrapping or packing material, but _the paper for newspaper_ doesn't sound natural.

Comment: Right, that's why I asked. Does "... for newspapers" sound OK?

Comment: It looks like a typo. It should be either “cleared to make newspaper” (which is still a little weird) or “cleared to make (the) paper for newspapers”.

Comment: As a reminder, questions on Stack Exchange are expected to demonstrate some initial efforts at research. *Newspaper* has a use as mass noun meaning *[the paper of a newspaper: newsprint](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/newspaper)* [MW].

Comment: But "newsprint" is probably a better choice of word anyway.

Comment: @choster It’s not idiomatic to say “make paper for newsprint”. Newsprint is paper, not made out of paper.

Comment: @colleenv In what way would it not be idiomatic? I might explain to my nephew *that's how they get the paper for construction paper* which is essentially the same formulation.

Comment: @choster To me that’s the equivalent of saying “Millions of seeds are planted every year to grow flowers for roses.” instead of “to grow roses” It seems a very odd thing to say to me, and it seems very obvious to me that the sentence has a typo because of the phrasing.

Comment: Newsprint and construction paper and tissue and so forth are finished goods, of which paper is one input, even though they themselves can also be described as a type of paper. You aren't growing flowers for roses, you're growing flowers for your flower bouquet, or roses for your rose garden.

Comment: @choster newsprint IS paper. It’s made from pulp, not paper. Paper airplanes are made from paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "newspaper" here is not acting as a *singular* noun, but an *uncountable* or *mass* noun. For instance, you can have "1 river", "2 rivers", etc; but you would not normally have "1 water" or "2 waters", only "some water" - "river" is countable, "water" is (normally) *uncountable*, so has no plural.

In English, many nouns can be both used in both *countable* and *uncountable* forms, with different meanings; in this case:

- As a countable noun, "newspaper" refers to either a single physical item (e.g. "I bought a newspaper from the shop"), or a single publication (e.g. "the Guardian is a better newspaper than the Daily Mail").
- As an uncountable noun, "newspaper" refers to *the material newspapers are made of* (e.g. "we throw away several tonnes of newspaper every week"). This is the sense used in your quote.

As pointed out in the comments, there is a bit of redundancy in "... to make the paper for newspaper" - if paper is the only ingredient, it would make more sense to say "... to make newspaper". If you think of "newspaper" as being the printed product, though, you could have both "the paper to make newspaper" and "the ink to make newspaper".

Answer (score 1):

According to [wordhippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/newspaper.html), newspaper can be both countable and uncountable, meaning both 'newspaper' and newspapers' are correct in each their specific cases.

In more general, commonly used, contexts, the plural form will be newspaper.

However, in more specific contexts, the plural form can also be newspapers
(e.g. in reference to various types of newspapers or a collection of newspapers.)

So in conclusion, the wording in the book was correct because it is more of a general talk about newspaper ;)

[Go read here for more information](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/newspaper.html)

Answer (score 1):

"Newspaper" can indeed be used as a mass noun, and is being used in that way in the example in the question, as the answer by IMSoP correctly indicates.

However the wording "to make the paper for newspaper" is odd, as several comments suggest, particularly those of ColleenV. Newspaper (also called "newsprint" ) is a **kind** of paper. It is not made from some other paper, but from pulp, as most papers are. Thus the example would be better as:

> Every year millions of acres of forest are cleared to make newspaper.

Even better would be:

> Every year millions of acres of forest are cleared to make  newsprint.

or

> Every year millions of acres of forest are cleared to make  newsprint for use in newspapers.

---

By the way to clarify the usage: [the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/newsprint) defines "Newsprint" as:

> paper made chiefly from groundwood pulp and used mostly for newspapers

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newsprint) says:

> Newsprint is a low-cost, non-archival paper consisting mainly of wood pulp and most commonly used to print newspapers and other publications

The [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/newsprint) defines "newsprint" as

> cheap, low quality paper that newspapers are printed on.

"Newsprint" means the paper, not the ink. It is, however, sometime used for the finished publication:

> John was surprised to find his doings discussed in newsprint.

Comment: "Newsprint" makes me think of the _ink_ component (the part you _print with_), so cutting down trees to make it sounds somewhat odd. Possibly, the writer of the sentence in question was implying that newspaper was made from both paper _and_ ink, and so qualified that it was the _paper_ component that came from trees.

Comment: @IMSOP [Werriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/newsprint) defines "Newsprint" as: "*paper made chiefly from groundwood pulp and used mostly for newspapers*" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newsprint) says "*Newsprint is a low-cost, non-archival paper consisting mainly of wood pulp and most commonly used to print newspapers and other publications*" [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/newsprint) defines it as "*cheap, low quality paper that newspapers are printed on*" "Newsprint" means the paper, not the ink.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I've learned a new word today.